# Import errors with the package @react-three/drei

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I get the same error no matter what I import from the drei package, I am sure I have installed all the necessary packages and the latest versions, but I have this odd error.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/Trail.js 104:38-54

export 'MeshLineGeometry' (imported as 'MeshLineGeometry') was not found in 'meshline' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/Trail.js 107:18-34

export 'MeshLineMaterial' (imported as 'MeshLineMaterial') was not found in 'meshline' (module has no exports)


ERROR in ./node_modules/meshline/dist/index.js 1:0-35

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './MeshLineGeometry' in 'C:\Users\anura\Desktop\mysite\node_modules\meshline\dist'
Did you mean 'MeshLineGeometry.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './MeshLineGeometry' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

Comment: Try downgrading to 9.40.0. I have the same issue with version 9.46.4.

Comment: @TheKalashnikov I'm at version 9.36.0 and have the problem too

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading not working solved it temporarily as follows.

- Copied the `index.js` from `node_modules/meshline/dist to lib/meshline` in the root folder
- Fixed by adding `.js` extensions to each line
- Updated build steps as in the screenshots

[Fixed index.js in lib/meshline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew2iC.png)

[Build steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dynQV.png)

Comment: Still doesn't work for me

Comment: You are right my mistake looks like I fixed it manually. Updating my answer with my solution